# Make pytest use a fixed date for the database

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest to test some mathematical functions. I want the database to think it's a date in the past.

For example, I would to set the database to think it is August 1, 2019.

Is there a way to configure that with pytest?

Currently my database is setup like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def autouse_db(db):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`freezegun`](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/) for monkeypatching `datetime` functions. Example:

```
import datetime
import pytest
from freezegun import freeze_time


@pytest.fixture
def fast_forward_to_2038():
    # use me to test the year 2038 problem
    with freeze_time('2038-01-19 03:14:08'):
        # year 2038 problem should be reproducible now
        yield


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fast_forward_to_2038')
def test_2038_problem():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 19, 03, 14, 08)
    ...
```

Check out more examples in package [readme](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/blob/master/README.rst).

Comment: I ended up just using the decorator with freezegun like this:

@freeze_time("2018-08-01")

Answer (score 1):

What ORM do you use and how you use dates in you query? 
Possible solutions if you use datetime in queries is to make simple fixture like

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def current_date():
    return datetime(2019, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Other way is to monkeyepatch datetime.now() function in tests.
At the end of the day this all is going from the point how you interact from python with database.

Comment: Using sql alchemy as the ORM, dates are setup like this:

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-04-23',"%Y-%m-%d")